# Variable number inputs to CNN

Tags: neural-networks, image-processing

In the image recognition problem I am trying to solve, we are supposed to develop a model that predicts the cost of a house based on images of several rooms in the house.  Each house has several images but not all houses have the same number of photos. Some houses have more photos, some have less. How can one setup a CNN to use such data?

Unfortunately, I cannot share any data because this is related to a problem I am solving at work.

Can someone point me towards sample code/problems/kaggle competitions that deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some things to try out:

1. Run each photo through a convnet to extract features, concat them and run the concatenated feature vector through a fully connected network to get the price. To deal with varying number of inputs, you could decide for a maximum amount of inputs per house, and use zero-filled placeholder for inputs for houses with less inputs than maximum. Given enough data, and enough variation in data, the model should learn to ignore placeholders by treating them as noise.
2. Have one model to predict the house price from an image. Predict house prices for multiple images separately, and average predictions afterwards.

Comment: Thank you! I will try out that solution. I will leave this question open for a few 6 days to see if there are other people who answer before marking your answer as the solution.  (Also, it appears that my upvote doesn’t count because my reputation here is less than 15)

Comment: Sure thing! Your problem seems interesting, let me know how it goes :). Working with neural nets is still relatively research level work - do expect this to take time.

Comment: I just want to point out that, in the first suggestion, you would need to decide what type of photo occupies which location in the concatenate feature. E.g., the order should bedroom 1, bedroom 2, kitchen, etc. If a house does not have bedroom 2, that region should be all zeros. This would make the whole learning stable. For the same reason, the concatenated features would have very large dimensionality since the type of photos could vary so much. As a first step, I recommend simply averaging the features from each photo. Later on, you can try using something like attention mechanism.